Is QFT discretisable similar to weather modelling or electromagnetic FDTD, and local, whereby you consider only local influences?
In classical electrodynamics, you can specify field, charge and current densities at each point on a grid or lattice.
f(t0, xn, yn, zn)
You can then rearrange Maxwell's equations and integrate for time evolution (Yee's method).
Let's say I have a valid field configuration specified at a point in time for some frame of reference, for the set of fields (Aμ, ψ), in Quantum Electrodynamics.
Can I perform a similar transformation here? In other words, can I write Aμ(tn+1, xn, yn, zn) as a function of Aμ(tn, x±0,1,2, yn±0,1,2, zn±0,1,2) and ψ(tn, xn±0,1,2, yn±0,1,2, zn±0,1,2).
The alternative would be that Aμ(tn+1, xn, yn, zn) is a function of A(tn+1) at all positions not just local ones.

Quantum field theory is a lot more complicated than that. A quantum field doesn't take a specific value at every point. Instead, for each classical field configuration $\phi(\mathbf{x})$, there is a quantum amplitude to be in that configuration. The amount of information you need to keep track of is infinitely greater.

Alternatively, you can follow the evolution of field operators, and those indeed obey a local differential equation. But at each point, you don't have a single number describing the field value at that point, instead you have to keep track of an infinite-dimensional operator.

Somewhat related older question without an answer but possibly worthwhile comments https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/744528/23615

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_field_theory
